# matrix operation in sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, matrix, sparkr

For creating matrix, the spark documentation given 4 data types 1. RowMatrix 2. IndexedRowMatrix 3. CoordinateMatrix and 4. Block matrix. but  all the data types are explained in scala, java and python. I want to perform matrix operation in spark using R. Is it possible to do distributive computation on matrix operation in sparkR?